# painless to convert miliseconds to hh:mm:ss

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, elasticsearch-painless

In my index i have field called `build duration` with `string` type, Since i want to visualize the `average` of build_duration In Line chart `Y-axis` i want to select `Average` but if i select it shows `The index pattern build-info does not contain any of the following compatible field types: number or histogram` So for this reason i am looking to create scripted field to calculate the build duration average. currently it is in milliseconds (`"build_duration" => "6409651"`) need help to convert into HH:mm:ss format. Have tried the below
but it is not working. So can someone help me to work this? Any help would be highly appreciated.

[image]

**Script:**

```
String millisecondsString = doc['build_duration.keyword'].value;
long milliseconds = 1000000;
long minutes = (milliseconds / 1000) / 60;
long seconds = (milliseconds / 1000) % 60;
ZoneId z = ZoneId.of("Z");
Instant instant = Instant.ofEpochMilli(milliseconds);
LocalDateTime l = LocalDateTime.ofInstant(instant, z);
return l;
```

**preview result**

```
[
 {
  "_id": "37361323",
  "build_duration": "1062735",
  "test": [
   "1970-01-01T00:16:40.000Z"
  ]
 },
 {
  "_id": "37200499",
  "build_duration": "1446172",
  "test": [
   "1970-01-01T00:16:40.000Z"
  ]
 },
```

Kibana Discover field result.

[image]

Comment: How is your `instant` defined? Seems we're missing something here

Comment: Currently it is having in this format `"build_duration" => "6409651"`

Comment: That's not what I mean. Where does `instant` come from here: `LocalDateTime.ofInstant(instant, z);`?

Comment: Oh sorry i missed it - `Instant instant = Instant.ofEpochMilli(milliSinceEpoch);`

Comment: OK now, where is `milliSinceEpoch` defined?

Comment: oh for testing purpose i was swapping, missied it, I have updated correctly now. the preview result added.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps I'm missing something but it seems there's some confusion between a **duration** and a **point in time**.

The duration of `6409651ms` equals `1h 46m 49s`. If you were to parse that as a date time (point in time) and didn't provide the *date*, ES would've put it at the beginning of the epoch (01.01.1970). While you *could* do that, it's somewhat unreasonable to think about durations and put them on a date axis...

Now, if you want to "prettify" a millisecond duration (convert into the format `hh:mm:ss`), you could do that with this script:

```
String millisecondsString = "6409651";
long seconds = Long.parseLong(millisecondsString, 10) / 1000;
long s = seconds % 60;
long m = (seconds / 60) % 60;
long h = (seconds / (60 * 60)) % 24;

return String.format("%02d:%02d:%02d", new def[] { h, m, s });
```

BTW the weird `new def[]` syntax in the last line [comes from here](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/issues/28696#issuecomment-367354660).

Comment: thanks Joe. Yes ideally it should show `hh:mm:ss` have tried with your code and for `1062735ms` it shows `[
 {
  "_id": "37361323",
  "build_duration": "1062735",
  "test": [
   "7:12:15"
  ]
 },`

Comment: My bad -- check my last edit. Needed to divide the ms to seconds first!

Comment: Added one more edit so that the hours always have 2 characters.

Comment: Preview results working perfectly, However in discover scripted field shows `Invalid date`. something i am missing?

Comment: Well the result is a string so your field cannot be a date... Change its type to string.

Comment: Okay, Now in discover it shows the duration perfectly. However tried to create `Line-Chart`
`Metrics: Yaxis, Aggregation:Average, Field: scripted_one`
`Buckets: Xaxis, Aggregation:Date-Histogram, Field:build_date, Minimum interval: Day` it shows below error.

`Search Error
Internal Server Error
search_phase_execution_exception
all shards failed`

Comment: OK I guess that's now out of scope of this question. Please ask a new one with screenshots and perhaps with the full error... If *this* answer helped you, feel free to accept & upvote it ;)